# Collapse on Scroll with Recycler View

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I am using [Collapse On Scroll](https://github.com/KlassenKonstantin/CollapseOnScroll) library and have replaced the list view with recycler view, but it does not scroll although the header effects are working. How do I make the recycler view scrollable

Can I have an example where recycler view touch/ scroll events are implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this library

https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview, I am guessing this should give you what you are looking for in terms of functionality and you can read through the library's code.

Comment: I read through the code but I didn't understand how to start using this library. If you used it, would you please tell me what exactly do I need to add to my project to be able to use it. I added the line to compile the library but is there any lib files to be added to the project? The posted examples doesn't make "how to use the lib" clear.